# Why is my Rails site failing to push to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have a Rails site which previously deployed without a problem to Heroku.  It worked fine until I added the following code to the `production.rb` file in order to make SendGrid work correctly.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

When I add this code the `git push heroku master` fails to push to Heroku.
However, the `git push origin master` works fine.  What could possibly be going wrong?

---

Here is the build log from Heroku:

```
  Rails.application.configure do

    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      :port           => '587',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :domain         => 'heroku.com',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }
    end
      # more code here

  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "AcuSimonv_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end



EDIT: production.rb file below


    Rails.application.configure do

    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      :port           => '587',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :domain         => 'heroku.com',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }



  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "AcuSimonv_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to     raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
    end
```

Comment: Do you have the env variables set in heroku?  I get this behavior when I try to push before the env variables are set up in heroku.

Comment: Fails how? What error is occurring?

Comment: @jeffdill2. The error says "build failed"

Comment: @Owen that's it? There's no backtrace? Your command line just says "build failed"?

Comment: @Rockwell Rice.  what are env variables and how do i set them? i have not had to do this before. the error seems to be related to this specific code that i added.

Comment: @jeffdill2. yes just says "build failed" on th eheroku website. i will add the build log.

Comment: @Owen :thumbsup: – the build log is what we're looking for.

Comment: you can do it in your heroku dashboard or the terminal.  To do it from dashboard go to you heroku.com account, click on the application, click on "settings", click the button that says "reveal config vars" and then enter in the env variables, so "SENDGRID_USERNAME" and "SENDGRID_PASSWORD" with the values entered into the field after them.

Comment: Looks like your app is failing because you have a syntax error in that file as well.

Comment: @Owen that backtrace tells you where you're having an issue – `SyntaxError: /tmp/build_5cbe4a41cfc117d8718d04c4287ffbda/config/environments/production.rb:100: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`. Line 100 of your `production.rb` file.

Comment: @Rockwell Rice.  "SENDGRID_USERNAME" and "SENDGRID_PASSWORD" already exist in the config vars.

Comment: Should be good to go then, look at @jeffdill2 's comment.

Comment: @jeffdill2. my production.rb file only goes up to line 99.  the last line of the production.rb file is "config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false".  I didnt write this line it was there by default.

Comment: @Owen if `config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false` is the last line of your `production.rb` file, then you're missing an `end`. i.e. line 100 should be `end`.

Comment: I added the "end" at the end. i am still getting the same error. any ideas?

Comment: @Owen make sure you commit your changes (adding the missing `end`) before pushing to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

> Running: rake assets:precompile
>
> rake aborted!
>
> SyntaxError:
>   /tmp/build_5cbe4a41cfc117d8718d04c4287ffbda/config/environments/production.rb:100:
>   syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

The error message states that there's a missing `end` keyword on line 100 in your `production.rb` file. Add that, commit changes, then push again.

Comment: i tried this and the error is still the same. except it says line 98

Comment: I think you have to remove the `end` on line 12 (after SendGrid config {}) because it's not supposed to be there then commit and push.

Comment: i removed the end from line 12 and still get the same error

Comment: did you stage and commit all changes? if so, please add how your `production.rb` looks right now

Comment: see production.rb in edited post. yes i did git add . then git push orgin master then git push heroku master

Comment: `production.rb` looks good. you're still getting the same error (missing keyword end)? maybe you should set up sengrid env variables in heroku as @Rockwell Rice suggested

Comment: @Owen you need to commit after running `git add .`. Eg. `git commit -m "Fix production.rb"`. Then run `git push heroku master`.

Comment: i did add then commit then push

Comment: @why is it still telling me to put "2nd" in line 98?  what is the end for? i see no need for another "end".

Comment: Do you have your code in a GitHub repo? I want to take a look at the changes